# After logstash imports data into es, the size of data changes

Tags: logstash

After logstash imports data into es, the size of data is 44g, and then automatically becomes 20g. Excuse me, why? If it is normal, how to quickly change from 44g to 20g.

Comment: This is not cause by logstash but probably most by Elasticsearch engine. Read some doc about Lucene/Elasticsearch and how it works to understand the gain that could be provide when you use this core engine compare to flat file.

Comment: @YLR ok, thank you